# Example of a weak mixing that is not Topological Mixing

Tags: general-topology, mixing

A continuous map $f:X\to X$ is called **Topologically transitive** or **TT** if for every pair of non-empty open sets $U,V$ in $X$ there exists $n\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $f^n(U)\cap V \neq \emptyset$.

A continuous map $f:X\to X$ is called **weak mixing** if $f\times f$ is TT.

and

A continuous map $f:X\to X$ is called **Topological Mixing** if for every pair of non-empty open sets $U,V$ in $X$ there exists $n_0\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $f^n(U)\cap V \neq \emptyset\ \forall\ n\ge n_0$.

We can prove that Topological Mixing $\implies $ Weak mixing $\implies$ TT.

We have a map that is TT but not weak mixing as

$f(x)=\begin{cases} 2x+1  & 0\le\ x\ \le\ \frac{1}{2} \\
-2x+3 & \frac{1}{2}\le\ x\ \le\ 1 \\ -x+2 & 1\le x\le 2 \end{cases}\\ $.

And irrational rotations of $S^1$ provides a map which is TT but not Topological Mixing.

I am looking for an example of a map which is a weak mixing but not Topological Mixing.

Any help here is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

Answer (score 0):

In ergodic theory, the Chacon transformation $T$ is weak mixing but not topological mixing.  A continuous version can be obtained as a shift on the sequence of 0's and 1's obtained by substituting at each stage 0010 for 0 and 1 for 1.  Start with 0 and at the next stage you get: 0010, then 0010 0010 1 0010, then 0010001010010 0010001010010 1 0010001010010.  Continue this process to produce an infinite sequence.  Take the closure under the topology obtained where open sets are cylinder sets (a finite number of positions around the zeroth position are defined).  Left-shift is continuous and will be weak mixing (TxT is topologically transitive), but $T$ will not be topological mixing.  If $h_n$ is length of the generating sequence at stage $n$, then $T^{h_n}$ will be the shift that does not mix small open sets.  I'm not sure if you are interested in this question anymore or found an answer. There are many references to the Chacon transformation, although there are actually two Chacon transformations.  I'm referring to the one sometimes called Chacon-3.  Chacon-2 is actually topologically mixing.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about how to define that transformation? And what space are you working on? The space of sequences of 0's and 1's or is it a subspace of that?